# p:selectOneMenu ajax does not fire within p:dataGrid

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu rendered for each row of my dataGrid. The problem is the method of the ajax listener is not called when the selection changes.

If I use the same selectOneMenu outside the dataGrid, it works fine. Same behaviour occurs with p:selectBooleanCheckbox.

XHTML page:

```
<h:form id="form2">
  <p:dataGrid id="gridC" widgetVar="gridC" 
    value="#{myBean.comp}" var="site" columns="1" rowIndexVar="siteIndex">
    <p:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{site.sito}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
      <p:selectOneMenu id="stato" value="#{site.stateId}" 
        required="true">
        <p:ajax update="@form :tabView:frm_buttons" global="false" 
          listener="#{myBean.testChangeState}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.siteStates}" var="s"
          itemLabel="#{s.state}" itemValue="#{s.stateId}" />
      </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
  </p:dataGrid>
</h:form>
```

Managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
  private SiteState siteStates;
  private Comp comp;
  // getters and setters...

  public void testChangeState() {
    System.out.println("Test change state fired.");
  }
}
```

SiteState bean:

```
public class SiteState implements Serializable {
  private String state;
  private String stateId;
  // getters and setters...
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code for your backing bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the secret.

The data grid is within a tab of an accordion panel, and I used an id like this:

```
<p:tab id="sito#{sito.idSitoStoccaggio}"
```

This is not the case, because it produces strange behaviours in some situations, like events not firing from within a data grid, for example.

Switching to:

```
<p:tab id="sito"
```

resolved my issue.